# Expected worker.ExecuteTask.IsCanceled to be true, but found False

Tags: c#, windows-services, xunit, worker-service

I create a worker service project. also, add a unit test project ( xunit ). this unit test failed each and every time.
[image]

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task ShouldCancelWorker()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = source.Token;
        await worker.StartAsync(token);

        source.Cancel();

        worker.ExecuteTask.IsCanceled.Should().BeTrue();
    }
```

it always returns true
any idea how to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you your logic for checking the token that is canceled ( token.IsCancellationRequested) is correct. In that case you should put a delay between source.Cancel() and  worker.ExecuteTask.IsCanceled.Should().BeTrue() in order to be able a pass one iteration in the worker execution loop.